# PHP Does not render on OS X even after configurations

Tags: php, apache, localhost, server

I am trying to develop a small application using PHP. I use a Mac OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion. I learnt that PHP is not by default activated on a Mac and so followed steps to activate PHP and configure it for my Mac.
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-configure-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enable-apache2-2-php5-on-apple-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/

Till yesterday, my Mac worked fine with at least the "It Works."

Now, the server itself seems not to be working!

When I load localhost, This is what it shows:[image: Apache Does not work!]

I am unable to understand what and where configuration is incorrect and how to get my Apache Server to start again.

Please help!!!! I'm at my wits end!

Comment: Solved! I think I should search more before I actually post here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution from here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131671/problem-accessing-localhost-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-it-was-working-fine-until-i

I apparently had made changes to the httpd.conf file which was not acceptable.

To detect issues with Apache: I ran: apachectl configtest
This line gave me the solution that works wonders!!